# ETIMEDOUT while using mysql2 with Express on AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, mysql2

I am using mysql2 package with the Express Framework, deployed over AWS Lamda. I have the provisioned concurrency set to 3 for Aws Lambda.

I am not directly connecting to MySQL. I have RDS Proxy in between.

I am getting the following error, randomly.

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "connect ETIMEDOUT",
    "code": "ETIMEDOUT",
    "errorno": "ETIMEDOUT",
    "syscall": "connect",
    "fatal": true,
    "stack": [
        "Error: connect ETIMEDOUT",
        "    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/var/task/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:178:17)",
        "    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)",
        "    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)"
    ]
}
```

Following is what my code looks like:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const mysql = require('mysql2');

class DBConnection {

    constructor() {

        var signer = new AWS.RDS.Signer({
            region: 'us-east-1',
            hostname: process.env.DB_HOST,
            port: 3306,
            username: process.env.DB_USER
        });
        
        let connectionConfig = {
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            user: process.env.DB_USER,
            database: process.env.DB_NAME,
            ssl: 'Amazon RDS',
            authPlugins: { mysql_clear_password: () => () => signer.getAuthToken() }
        };
        
        this.db = mysql.createConnection(connectionConfig);

    }

    query = async (sql, values) => {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            this.db.execute(sql, values, (error, result) => {

                if (error) {
                    reject(error);
                    return;
                }

                resolve(result);

            });

        });

    }
}

module.exports = new DBConnection().query;
```

```
const results = await query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_listens FROM analytics WHERE event_name="PLAYED"');
```

Any clue where the issue can be?

Comment: I am not very sure but, it seems since it is lambda functions it creates an instance for every call, and you are not releasing your connection (destroying connection), when there is less connection (fewer lambda function instance) it works, when concurrent multiple lambdas are active it gets connection time out.
try to release connection as work is done, I am not sure how it is going to scale though with humongous traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `AWS Lambda function` it's better to use `mysql.createPool` instead of `mysql.createconnection`. I don't know what's the specific reason but using `mysql.createconnection` instead of `mysql.createPool` has caused problems for me as well. It's also necessary to `release` the connection when the query goes successful.